# Trigger segue from UITableViewRowAction

Tags: ios, swift, segue, uitableviewrowaction

I've read many SO posts about this problem, but unfortunately none of the answers have solved my issue. I have a `UIViewController` with a `TableView` inside of it (I set it up this way for a specific UI format I wanted), and as of now if the user swipes to the left, a `delete` and `edit` button show up. My `delete` action works fine, but every iteration I've tried of `edit` so far has given me a `SIGABRT / terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException` error.

My `ViewController` class has the `UIViewController`, `UITableViewDataSource`, and `UITableViewDelegate` protocols added. The code for my tableView(editActionsForRowAt:) function is as follows:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

    // Delete action
    let deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.default, title: "Delete", handler: { (action, indexPath) -> Void in

        // Delete action code works fine

    })

    deleteAction.backgroundColor = GlobalPropertyKeys.LovalyticsRed

    let editAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.default, title: "Edit") {(action, indexPath) -> Void in

        // Will explain what I've tried so far below this

        print("Edit tapped.")
    }

    editAction.backgroundColor = GlobalPropertyKeys.LovalyticsBlue

    return [deleteAction, editAction]

}
```

All the answers I found on SO involved variations of creating the segue in IB from my `ViewController` to the destination screen, setting an identifier for the segue, and then calling that segue using `performSegue(withIdentifier:sender:)`.

So far I have tried:

1.

```
    if let topController = UIApplication.topViewController() {
        topController.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueToEditListItem", sender: topController)
    }
```

2.

```
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueToEditListItem", sender: self)
```

3.

```
    tableView.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueToEditListItem", sender: tableView)
```

4. Tried connecting the segue from the `TableView` instead of from the `ViewController`

And probably a few more variations of the above that I deleted instead of commenting them out. Each time, I get a `SIGABRT` error when clicking `edit`, which I always associate with incorrectly connected `@IBOutlets`. I checked to make sure the segue was connected correctly, and when I remove any mention of the segue my app works fine (the `edit` button prints "Edit tapped."), so that makes me think there's a problem with my `ViewController` not recognizing the segue in my .swift file.

I've spent several hours trying to figure this out and have failed pretty miserably, so any help / advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: do you have a repo for it share ??

Comment: Quick test... `self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueToEditListItem", sender: nil)` segues to the next view controller without issue. How are you creating the Segue in Storyboard? Do you also have a `prepare(for segue: ...)` func implemented? If so, is that where the error is occurring? Or, is the error actually happening in the target view controller?

Comment: Solution 2 should be the one to use. Now when you try it, since it seems to crash, could you give us the crash log?

Comment: @Sh_Khan I don't, but here's a pastebin of the file in question https://pastebin.com/nWiUuzTr .

Comment: @DonMag I tried it that way and still got the SIGABRT error. I do not have prepare(for segue:) implemented, should I? The error is occurring in my AppDelegate.

Comment: @Larme here's a pastebin for a crash log from today https://pastebin.com/3xb4nRuf

Comment: @DonMag I meant to mention this in the above comment, but I created the segue in my Storyboard by control-dragging from my UIViewController to the destination NavigationViewController, setting it to be push, and then assigning it the segue identifier.

Comment: By the way, you don't need to automatically pass the class asking for segue as `sender`. If you don't have any parameter to use inside `prepareForSegue` then just send `nil`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Identifier", sender: self)` should works. 
If your problem is about `@IBOutlets` you should check your Outlets again.
And if you can write your console log where there is description of your crash.

Comment: GAH. That was it. Since I was seguing to an edit screen, I had duplicated the add version which had some outlets in it. That's what was causing the crash, ugh what a stupid mistake! Thanks for the point in the right direction @arash!